# Stopping spam in web page

Tags: spam-prevention

So right now my only spam protection is going to be to check all incoming messages against this table, http://www.stopforumspam.com/downloads/, that I have imported into my database, and if the IP is found, their message will not be posted.

We don't really want to hinder usability by having one of those "Type what you see..." or a sort of e-mail confirm system similar to Craigs List.

Will this IP check be enough to get rid of (most) spam comments, or should I really look into adding something else. Maybe there is some free plugin that I haven't found that doesn't hinder usability and will help us out more?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate of a few questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940887 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437577 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296686 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849077 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448665 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754613 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470274 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221674 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356337 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360041

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577918 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686772 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223937 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613023 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260128 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511412 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718747 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676368 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622433 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122623 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485106 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217187 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230453 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59560

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go :) http://akismet.com/

There's an API, you send them the comment body and they reply if it's spam or not. This is (maybe the best) spam hunting service, they have large word databases and good self-learning filters.

Additionally, it's free for personal use. I don't know how much it costs for business.

I'm in no way affiliated with them, I just found it by chance a couple of years ago.

Answer (score 0):

akismet.com offers a quality service that will protect your site. Depending on the nature of your site there may be a fee.  If your site is a personal blog they have a "WHAT IS AKISMET WORTH TO YOU?" plan where you can choose to pay $0. They would prefer that you pay $3 to $5 per month.

Answer (score 0):

There's a reason captchas ("type what you see..." things) and email confirmation lists exist - there's always someone attempting to circumvent your site's security for personal gain.  In all likelihood this will extend beyond spam, as well.

Just keep in mind that you're putting your trust in any external solution that you go with (which is why things like in-application email confirmations and captchas have gotten popular, considering they're not too difficult to implement and you have full control over them).

Comment: Exactly, easy to implement, so you should implement them should the external solution fail, but still just go with what does the trick.

Comment: I definitely didn't mean to imply that an external solution shouldn't be considered, just that the possible consequences of all options should be considered.  I would definitely recommend implementation and testing of the internal solution before the external solution fails, however - you don't want to be stuck with nothing. :)